# appended button onclick don't fire Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, append, appendto

I am having a button which appends 2 textfields and a button in a table td, however the problem is that the onclick function of the appended button don't fire. anyone sees the problem?
code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add").click(function() {
            $(".no_border").append("<br /><label>Co-author email:</label><input type='text' name='author_email'/><label>Co-author Level:</label><input type='text' name='author_level'/><input id='save' type='button'name='save' value='Add'/>");
    });
});
</script>
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($co_authors)) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td>{$row['author_email']}</td>
            <td>{$row['coauthor_level']}</td>";
            ?><td><button class='remove' id='remove' name='remove' email="<?php echo $row['author_email'] ?>"
            paper="<?php echo $row['paper_id'] ?>">Remove</button></td>
            </tr><?
            ?><td colspan="3" class="no_border"><button class="add" name="add"></button>
            <label id="add" class="cursor_pointer"> Add more co-authors</label></td><?
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the jQuery `.on()` functionality to access elements created after the DOM has loaded.

More specific info can be found in the jQuery manual here:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#add", function() {
    alert("aaaaaaaaaaa");
} );
```

In jQuery < 1.7 , this was previously used like so:

```
$( "#add" ).live( "click", function( e ) {} );
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in the jQuery document `ready` function:

```
$(function() {
   $("#add").click(function() {
      $(".no_border").append("<br /><label>Co-author email:</label><input type='text' name='author_email'/><label>Co-author Level:</label><input type='text' name='author_level'/><input id='save' type='button'name='save' value='Add'/>");
   });
});
```

For more details see: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Alternatively you could use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (`.on` being the preferred method from 1.7).

```
   $(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
      $(".no_border").append("<br /><label>Co-author email:</label><input type='text' name='author_email'/><label>Co-author Level:</label><input type='text' name='author_level'/><input id='save' type='button'name='save' value='Add'/>");
   });

   $("#add").live('click', function() {
      $(".no_border").append("<br /><label>Co-author email:</label><input type='text' name='author_email'/><label>Co-author Level:</label><input type='text' name='author_level'/><input id='save' type='button'name='save' value='Add'/>");
   });
```

Comment: this is already done, i am just adding part of the code for explanation.

Comment: To use `.on()` for elements loaded after dom ready your selector has to find an element already in the dom. The correct use of `.on()` in this case is `$(document).on('click','#add', function() { })`. (Using `.on()` the way you've indicated is the same as using `.click( handler )` )

Comment: @nbrooks: thanks for pointing that out, have updated the example of `.on()`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have to use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), they make the script recognize elements created after `$(document).ready()` be called.

For example:

**before jQuery 1.7**

```
$("#add").live("click", function() {
    ...
```

**jQuery 1.7 and higher**

```
$("#add").on("click", function() {
    ...
```