# want to use the id of a button which written in append

Tags: jquery

' Add phone no '

this is written in this code

```
$("#fieldsetnew-add").click(function () {
        var addnewfieldset = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .addClass('fieldset1-inner-phoneno');
        addnewfieldset.after()
                .html(
'<fieldset style="background-color:#B0C4DE;moz-border-radius:15px;-webkit-border-radius:15px;" class="defaultfeild" >' +
        '<br>' +
        '<br>' +
        '<label> label :</label>'+
        '<input  type="label" value="labelname"  placeholder="">'+
        '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="remove" >remove this profile</button>'+
        '<br>' +
        '<br>' +
        '<label>Email :</label>' +
        '<input  type="email" value="labelname"  placeholder="me@example.com">'+
        '<br>'  + 
        '<br>' +
        '<div>'+
        '<br>'+
        '<div id="TextBoxesGroup1">'+
        '<div id="TextBoxDiv1">'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<button class="btn btn-success" id="fieldsetnew-addphone" > Add phone no </button>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<br>'+
        '<br>'+
        '</fieldset>'+
        '<br>'+
        '<br>');
        addnewfieldset.appendTo("#fieldset-new-add");

    });
```

how can i use the id of button ...........
i want to add input box, button when click on "add phone no" button...............

Comment: after this code introduce `on()` listener - `$(document).on("click","#fieldsetnew-addphone", function....`

Comment: possible duplicate of [appended button onclick don't fire Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463109/appended-button-onclick-dont-fire-jquery)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah, as Grant said: use `on()` method. Because the ID created after jQuery is initialized, so it can't access it with other method like `bind()`. Honestly I've never used `bind()` before and I always use `on()`. It's the newest method of all. It's good to know that behind the scene, helper methods like `bind()` and `live()` they're all pointed to `on()` method.

Something else which is not related to your question but good to mention is to try not to mix your JavaScript with HTML. You can instead use template like [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: It would be good if I could know the reason why someone gave a negative vote to my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind to events of dynamically added elements which acts to:

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

So, for example:

```
$("#fieldsetnew-addphone").on("click", function(e) { 
  // event handler code
});
```

Comment: Does this version of on create the "live" binding?  I've found I had to use the $(document).on(...) version, otherwise it didn't bind to dynamically added events.

Comment: This version of `on` doesn't delegate the event.

Comment: I've not had such noted issues with this before, that might be more indicative of other problems with your document. Not sure what you mean by "live" in this context, yes it's "live" in the sense of being "on-the-fly", but not "live" in the sense of using the `live` method (which was deprecated a while back.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the click event to an element that is present on page load, as shown here:

```
$('body').on('click', '#fieldsetnew-addphone', function(){
    // do something
});
```